# How to use C# Interactive with a UWP project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Working on a UWP app.
I need to play with the API of UWP using C# Interactive window, but it doesn't seem to know about this API. It seems to only load API of classic .Net.

How can I load UWP assemblies in C# interactive so that I can play with the API in Visual Studio 2015?

Also, the option "Initialize Interactive with Project" doesn't show up in the context menu of my project.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should add references. For example:

```
#r "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd"
```

or

```
#r "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd"
```